# How to read body from response with status 101 Switching Protocols

Tags: go, kubernetes, spdy

I am connected to a server, in Kubernetes cluster, with POST request and headers to upgrade the request. I am using the following function:

```
func PostRequest(client *http.Client, url string, bodyData []byte) (*http.Response, error){
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(bodyData))
    //req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + BEARER_TOKEN)
    req.Header.Set("X-Stream-Protocol-Version", "v2.channel.k8s.io")
    req.Header.Set("X-Stream-Protocol-Version", "channel.k8s.io")
    req.Header.Set("Upgrade", "SPDY/3.1")
    req.Header.Set("Connection","upgrade")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    resp, err := (*client).Do(req)

    return resp, err
}
```

After I received the response, I tried to read it but it stuck when I read the body:

```
url2 := "https://<serveri_ip>:10250/exec/default/mypod/mycontainer?command=ls&command=/&input=1&output=1&tty=1"

resp, err := PostRequest(api.GlobalClient, url2, []byte(""))
fmt.Println(r.Status)
fmt.Println(r.Header)
bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) // -> it stuck here
fmt.Println(string(bodyBytes))
```

I suppose it tried to open websocket, so I tried to use [gorilla websocket library](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) like that:

```
u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: "<node_ip>:10250", Path: "/exec/default/mypod/mycontainer?command=ls&command=/&input=1&output=1&tty=1"}

interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("dial:", err)
}
defer c.Close()
```

But it printed an error:

> 2020/04/04 20:51:25 dial:websocket: bad handshake

What I am doing wrong?
How can I read response body from status "Switching Protocols"

Comment: Regarding use of the Gorilla package.  The error indicates that the server did not reply with a web socket handshake.  The endpoint may have failed the handshake for a number of reasons: the endpoint does not support the protocol, auth failure, redirect, etc.  Print the response returned from Dial to debug the issue. Also, the 101 response is used in other protocols such as spdy and h2.

Comment: I think this is because the endpoint is using SPDY. So I need to check how to read from SPDY protocol. I am checking this project: https://github.com/amahi/spdy/

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect here. You are doing an Upgrade request - there is no response body for this but if the response is successful (i.e. also an Upgrade) you need to continue with the new protocol. If you don't know how to handle the new protocol you requested (i.e. SPDY, not Websockets or something else) you should not request it.

Comment: I don't know how to handle the new protocol by I need to. Because this is how the endpoint works, they are working with SPDY. So I am trying to understand how can I use this protocol to read it. I tried the SPDY library I wrote above but still didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with Kubernetes [go-client](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) library:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "time"

    restclient "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/remotecommand"
)


func main(){

    /*req.Header.Add("X-Stream-Protocol-Version", "v4.channel.k8s.io")
    req.Header.Add("X-Stream-Protocol-Version", "v3.channel.k8s.io")
    req.Header.Add("X-Stream-Protocol-Version", "v2.channel.k8s.io")
    req.Header.Add("X-Stream-Protocol-Version", "channel.k8s.io")
    req.Header.Add("Connection", "upgrade")
    req.Header.Add("Upgrade", "SPDY/3.1")*/
    //url2 := "https://123.123.123.123:10250/exec/default/my-pod/nginx?command=ls&command=/&input=1&output=1&tty=1"
    tr := &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConns:       10,
        IdleConnTimeout:    30 * time.Second,
        DisableCompression: true,
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    config := &restclient.Config{
        Host:                "https://123.123.123.123:10250",
        APIPath:             "/exec/default/my-pod/nginx",
        TLSClientConfig:     restclient.TLSClientConfig{
            Insecure: true,
        },
        Transport:           tr,
    }

    url3 := &url.URL{
        Scheme:     "https",
        Opaque:     "",
        User:       nil,
        Host:       "123.123.123.123:10250",
        Path:       "/exec/default/my-pod/nginx",
        RawPath:    "",
        RawQuery:   "command=ls&command=/&input=1&output=1&tty=1",
    }
    exec, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(config, "POST", url3)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Thanks for this blog post https://www.henryxieblogs.com/2019/05/
    err = exec.Stream(remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:  os.Stdin,
        Stdout: os.Stdout,
        Stderr: os.Stderr,
        Tty:true,
    })

    fmt.Println(err)
}
```